# Как очистить кэш и куки chrome и mozilla из консоли?

Tags: консоль

Вопрос в заголовке. интересует команда очистки кэша и куков

Answer (score 3):

Хром можно запустить с параметрами

```
-disable-application-cache –media-cache-size=1 –disk-cache-size=1
```

или указать папку где будут хранится кеш

```
 --disk-cache-dir=папка
```

И из консоли удалить все из этой папки

Answer (score 2):

### **Chrome:**

Во вкладке Network можно поставить галочку "Disable Cache" и обновить страницу:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Куки можно найти во вкладке Application (в старых версиях - во вкладке Resourcses). Удаляются кнопкой delete:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

### **Firefox:**

Вкладка хранилище:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если у вас такой вкладки нет, надо включить её в настройках:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]